# Make windows form panel a pdfpage using PDFSharp? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, panel, pdfsharp

My application uses a panel to resemble a template that the user fills in and then prints.

However, they can end up having over 300 pages and my routine that makes the PDF slows down, takes up too much memory and then ultimately crashes with the message of either "OutofMemoryException" or "Invalid Parameter".

The method I use is; loading the revelant information onto the page and then turning it into a bitmap image to place on the PDFPage.

As discovered this really hasn't worked, any suggestions?

Btw I use PDFSharp to make this.

Routine that handles this;

```
For i = 0 To Count - 1
                If i = 0 Then ConditionReportConfig.SwitchPage5(Pages(i), False) Else ConditionReportConfig.SwitchPage5(Pages(i), True)
                If WithPics = True And ConditionReportConfig.PG5.PbxAddress(2) <> "" And ConditionReportConfig.PG5.txt_Occupier5.Enabled = True Then
                    frm_MsgAttachment.pbx_Picture.Image = Image.FromFile(ConditionReportConfig.PG5.PbxAddress(2))
                    Dim PicPage As PdfPage = PDFDoc.AddPage
                    PicPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
                    Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(PicPage)
                    Dim img As XImage
                    Dim xBitmap As Bitmap
                    PicPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
                    xBitmap = New Bitmap(2480, 3508)
                    frm_MsgAttachment.pbx_Picture.DrawToBitmap(xBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, xBitmap.Width, xBitmap.Height))
                    img = xBitmap
                    xgr.DrawImage(img, 6, 5, 2300, 3508)
                    xgr.Dispose()
                    xgr = Nothing
                    xBitmap.Dispose()
                    xBitmap = Nothing
                    GC.Collect()
                End If
                Dim CDR5 As PdfPage = PDFDoc.AddPage
                CDR5.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
                GFX = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(CDR5)
                Bitmap = New Bitmap(ConditionReportConfig.PG5.Panel1.Width, ConditionReportConfig.PG5.Panel1.Height)
                ConditionReportConfig.PG5.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height))
                BXImage = Bitmap
                GFX.ScaleTransform(0.82)
                GFX.DrawImage(BXImage, 0, 25)
                GFX.Dispose()
                GFX = Nothing
                Dim valu = frm_Main.pgb_Load.Value
                frm_Main.SetPrgBarValue(valu + tem)
            Next
```

Comment: In the snippet you do not dispose `img`, `Bitmap` and `BXBitmap` - not sure if this makes a difference. This workaround should help: save, close and dispose the PDF document periodically (e.g. after 50 pages), open it and add more pages. This reduces the memory footprint of PDFsharp. BTW: You'll get smaller and better PDFs if you add text instead of "screen shots". MigraDoc (bundled with PDFsharp) can be used for that purpose.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that I didn't dispose of the other variables, the only reason I haven't used Migradoc is becuase the Panel acts as a template form with pictureboxes and textboxes etc.. Otherwise I would've used MigraDoc for simple text and paragraphing,

Comment: Then try the Close/Re-open workaround. Haven't tried it myself, but others reported success.